# HTTParty not setting configuration parameters

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm using the **HTTParty** gem to post a request on another website of mine.
In my dedicated class I define some defaults according to HTTParty's [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods#base_uri-instance_method):

```
require 'httparty'

class Notifier

  include HTTParty
  base_uri "my_awesome_site.com"
  basic_auth "an_awesome_client", "megasecretkey"

  ...

end
```

Then within such class I have my `notify` method posting the actual request:

```
def notify
  ...
  result = HTTParty.post( '/receiver.json', 
                         :query => some_message_of_mine_as_a_hash)
  ...
end
```

Everything seems to be set up correctly, yet the connection fails. Debugging the method I find out that at the moment of the request HTTParty's `default_options` Hash is empty.
What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included the `HTTParty` module in your `Notifier` class. This makes the methods defined within that module available on your class. When you call `base_uri` and `base_auth`, you're setting configuration on `Notifier`, not within `HTTParty` itself.

In your `notify` method you should be calling `post` directly instead of against `HTTParty`

```
result = post( '/receiver.json', 
               :query => some_message_of_mine_as_a_hash )
```

See the very last line of **[this example](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/basic.rb)**. Notice, the call from outside the class is on `Partay.post`, not `Partay.HTTParty.post`.